# Bug in ROS_INFO_STREAM?

Tags: ros, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a stringstream that I'm using to store some debug information.  Every so often, I try to print it out.  I have found that

```
string s = ss.str();
ROS_INFO_STREAM(s);
```

works just as expected, the contents of ss are displayed in a message.  But an operation that I feel should be identical,

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM( (ss.str()) );
```

results in nothing at all being displayed,
except of course the usual ROS_INFO header "[ INFO]..."

Any ideas on why this could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31790/bug-in-ros_info_stream?/) by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably a bug in the implementation of the macro ROS_INFO_STREAM. Bug reports should go to the corresponding bug tracker, for rosconsole use the trac [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2